# Pandas to group columns into a list and count occurance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe as below and I want to group by people's name, to join the month sales into a list for each person, before counting the occurrence of each.

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Mike","Mike","Mike","Kate","Kate","Zeb","Zeb","Philip","Philip","Herman",],
["A4","A2","A4","A5","A6","A2","A6","A4","A4","A6"], 
["A6","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A6","A5","A5","A5"], 
["A3","A4","A5","A4","A6","A4","A6","A6","A5","A2"],
["A3","A5","A5","A5","A5","A4","A2","A3","A5","A2"]]).T

df.columns = ["Name",   "Jan",  "Feb",  "Mar",  "Apr"]
```

I tried below but none of them getting closer to what's desired:

```
df_1 = pd.crosstab([df['Name']],[df['Jan'],df['Feb'],df['Mar'],df['Apr']])
df_1 = df.groupby(['Name','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr']).size()
df_1 = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'].agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

The wanted output is like:

```
Mike: A3(4),A4(3),A5(2),A6(2),A2(1)
```

What's the right way to work it out?

Thank you.

Comment: Something simple like a `stack` and `groupby.value_counts`? `df.set_index('Name').stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how looks final DataFrame, so you can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)  with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('Name')
df_1 = pd.crosstab(df1['Name'], df1['value']).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df_1)
        A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
Name                      
Herman   2   0   0   1   1
Kate     0   2   1   3   2
Mike     1   4   3   3   1
Philip   0   1   2   4   1
Zeb      2   1   2   0   3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an equivalent solution to using `stack` as @cs95 suggested:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Mike","Mike","Mike","Kate","Kate","Zeb","Zeb","Philip","Philip","Herman",],
["A4","A2","A4","A5","A6","A2","A6","A4","A4","A6"], 
["A6","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A6","A5","A5","A5"], 
["A3","A4","A5","A4","A6","A4","A6","A6","A5","A2"],
["A3","A5","A5","A5","A5","A4","A2","A3","A5","A2"]]).T

df.columns = ["Name",   "Jan",  "Feb",  "Mar",  "Apr"]

df_1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_name='A', var_name='Count' )

df_1.groupby(['Name', 'A']).count().reset_index()

    Name   A  Count
0   Herman  A2      2
1   Herman  A5      1
2   Herman  A6      1
3     Kate  A3      2
4     Kate  A4      1
5     Kate  A5      3
6     Kate  A6      2
7     Mike  A2      1
8     Mike  A3      4
9     Mike  A4      3
10    Mike  A5      3
11    Mike  A6      1
12  Philip  A3      1
13  Philip  A4      2
14  Philip  A5      4
15  Philip  A6      1
16     Zeb  A2      2
17     Zeb  A3      1
18     Zeb  A4      2
19     Zeb  A6      3
```